# My C++ program has trouble calculating this series for Euler's number

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stack-overflow, series, eulers-number

[image]

Here is the C++ program i wrote to solve the above series:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int a)
{
    if (a > 1)
        return a * factorial(a - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}

float series(float x, int n, float b)
{
    if (abs(pow(x, n) / factorial(n)) < pow(10, -6) || abs(pow(x, n) / factorial(n)) == pow(10, -6)) { return b; }
    else return b = (pow(x, n) / factorial(n)) + series(x, n + 1, b);
}

int main()
{
    float x;
    cout << "Enter x: "<<endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "E^x = " << series(x,0,0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine when abs(x) < 2 but when abs(x) >= 2 this error appears:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00F02539 in 33b.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack
>   overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00F22FF8). occurred
>   [image]

I want to know why does this happen and how can i fix it?

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: Sorry, question added.

Comment: Consider calculating `abs(pow(x, n) / factorial(n)` just once per iteration. Beyond make the code much easier to read, it would help performance for debug builds, and in case the compiler fails to optimize out the redundancy.

Comment: What input did you provide to generate that error?

Comment: Note that there is no fundamental integer type that is guaranteed to be able to represent a value greater than !20. `int` will likely fail well before that.

Comment: The program works fine with x = 0,1,-1. Any number smaller or larger will cause the shown errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is too deep recursion. Consider loop instead.

```
float series(float x)
{
    const float epsilon = 1e-6f;
    double error = 1;
    double res = 1.f;
    int iter = 1;
    while (abs(error) > epsilon) {
        error *= (x / iter++);
        res += error;
        cout << error << endl;
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "E^x = " << series(3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

To be clearer about what happens:

When you call a function inside another function, the context of the parent function is saved to make room for the new context. When you make millions of inception, the memory stack in charge to save these context is full and overflows.

This is a Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, this clearly is the problem. Look at the small logo up right, you'll see an illustration of a stack overflow.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois yes, funnily the question is about this.

Comment: @Yola Just asking, what does writing "double res = 1.f" mean for "res" (instead of, you know: "double res = 1") ? I'm new to C++.

Comment: @TrầnĐứcHiếu `1.` is `double` literal, `1.f` is `float` literal. I changed type to `double`, but forgot to change literal, correct would be `double res = 1.;`. And just `1` is literal for `int`

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <cstdlib>
 using namespace std;
 int factorial[200];
 int Factorial(int a)
 {    if(a>0){
     factorial[a]=a * factorial[a-1];
         return factorial[a];
    }
    else
    factorial[a]=1;
    return 1;

 }

 double series(double x, int n, double b)
 {   double temp=(abs(pow(x, n)) / Factorial(n));
     if (temp <= 0.000001) { return b; }
     else return (temp + series(x, n + 1, b));
 }

 int main()
 {
     float x;
     cout << "Enter x: "<<endl;
     cin >> x;
     cout << "E^x = " << series(x,0,0);
     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

umm this solution is working. all i did was i took your code removed abs(pow(x, n) / factorial(n)) wherever its repeating and intialised to a new variable temp. then instead of < || == u can directly put <=. and rather than invoking a a function to calculate .000001 every time you could just give that value to reduce time further. however i believe that the reason why the code may not have worked is too much recursion. so for factorials i used dynamic programming to reduce its complexity. the above code is working perfectly fine.